# Default parameter value for a TSomething in Delphi

Tags: delphi, parameters, default-parameters

I'd like to know if this is possible in Delphi (or if there's a clean way around it):

```
type
 TSomething = record
  X, Y : Integer;
 end;
```

`GetSomething( x, y )` -> Returns record with those values.

... and then you have this function with `TSomething` as parameter, and you want to default it as

```
function Foo( Something : TSomething = GetSomething( 1, 3 );
```

The compiler spits an error here, however I'm not sure if there's a way around it!

Can this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to use overloaded procedures:

```
program TestOverloading;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  TSomething = record
    X,Y : integer;
  end;

const
  cDefaultSomething : TSomething = (X:100; Y:200);

procedure Foo(aSomething : TSomething); overload;
begin
  writeln('X:',aSomething.X);
  writeln('Y:',aSomething.Y);
end;

procedure Foo; overload;
begin
  Foo(cDefaultSomething);
end;

begin
  Foo;
  readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 12):

Use overloading:

```
procedure Foo(const ASomething: TSomething); overload;
begin
  // do something with ASomething
end;

procedure Foo; overload;
begin
  Foo(GetSomething(1, 3));
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a class instead of a record and *something* like this would do it:

```
TSomething = class
public 
  X: integer;
  Y: integer
end;

procedure Foo(Something: TSomething = nil);
begin
  if (Something = nil) then
    Something := GetSomething(1, 3);
  ...
end;
```

Comment: To exclude some RTTI overhead, X and Y could be declared as 'public' instead of implicit 'published'

Comment: Thank you @mjustin for pointing this out. My implicit assumption was, that the directive to control the generation of RTTI is set to the default value: `{$M-}`. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If you use a pointer instead of the record type you can use `nil` as default value:

```
type
  TSomething = record
    X, Y : Integer;
  end;

  PSomething = ^TSomething;

function Foo(Something: PSomething = nil);
```

Actually, passing pointers as parameters is usually faster because it avoids copying blocks of memory.